# Fast algorithm for n-rooks completion puzzle

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, np

I am motivated by the post, [Complexity of n-queens-completion](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/38972/495). I am interested in completion problem of non-attacking rooks on a chessboard.

**Input:** Given a chessboard of size × with − rooks placed in non-attacking positions, and certain chessboard diagonals represented by multi-set of integers  = { <sub>1</sub>, <sub>2</sub>, ...,  }

**Output:** Can we place additional  rooks such all  rooks are non-attacking and each new rook is placed on exactly one diagonal in ?

I suspect that the problem is NP-complete. Is there an efficient (fast) algorithm?

P.S. From comments, the multi-set of diagonals D defines parallel diagonals. For diagonal j, the sum of x and y coordinates of any cell on that diagonal is equal to j. This implies that there are no crossing diagonals. So, Only parallel diagonals (only diagonals, no anti-diagonals).

Comment: A variant Posted on TCS SE without an answer.  https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53207/complexity-of-n-rooks-completion

Comment: I prefer Python if you find an efficient algorithm.

Comment: @AndyG a1 and a3 are the same color... :)

Comment: Not sure I am misunderstanding the question but this is basically the same as the queen problem expect you are allowed to place place them on the top left to bottom right diagonal in attacking positions?

Comment: @Asthor For Diagonal j,  the sum of x and y coordinates of  any cell on that diagonal is equal to j .

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding this completely, but in general the rook problem is trivial as the basic algorithm would just be to place all rooks on `1,1` to `n,n` coordinates? But to make this more complicated you could block that they are placed on specific diagonals. That is any diagonal that fits with where the next is `k+1,k+1`. But that would leave the same trivial algorithm as you could just place all rooks on the diagonal going from `1,n` to to `n.1`. But if you block both of those diagonal direction I am not sure how this would differ from the Queens problem?

Comment: @Asthor, this is not the Queens problem, since rooks may share some diagonals. Even the to-be-placed rooks may (have to) share some diagonals, since  is a multi-set. And obviously the diagonals *not* in  are not allowed to be used.  defines exactly how many rooks have to be placed on each possible diagonal on the board. This is a non-trivial problem.

Comment: The pre-placed rooks are a red herring, you can always throw them away with their associated verticals and horizontals (and some instances of the diagonals) and end up with a k\*k board with *some* multiset of diagonals (not necessarily of size k).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, I'l not sure that is true. Imagine a 4x4 chessboard (X=abcd, Y=1234), with a rook on c3. Then let's say that the multiset has the diagonal b1-c2-d3 in it. Obviously that means there should be a new rook on b1. But now remove the pre-placed rook's row and column so we get a 3x3 chessboard. How would that multiset now have to look such that there should be a rook on b1? I don't see how this is a red herring (yet).

Comment: @trincot Oh it will not be a diagonal any more, just a set of allowed fields. My mistake was that I stopped to think about diagonals and started to think about arbitrary sets of allowed fields instead. But this shouldn't change the problem too much.

Comment: *"and each new rook is placed on exactly one diagonal in ?"*: so if  has crossing diagonals, then the solution cannot have a rook on their crossing square. Is that right?

Comment: @trincot The are no crossing diagonals. So, Only parallel diagonals (only diagonals, no anti-diagonals).

Comment: Oh, that is important information. That was not clear from the question. Can you update the question? Are those \ diagonals or / diagonals?

Comment: @trincot According to your lableing in your answer, the are / diagonals. For any, diagonal j, the sum of x and y coordintes of any cell is constant (equals to j).

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer to only assume such diagonals.

Comment: @trincot Nice. I guess the run-time is exponential in the worst case. Right?

Comment: Yes, it is non polynomial in the worst case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [constraint satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem), and more particularly a [SAT problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), where each boolean variable corresponds to a square on the chess board, indicating whether it gets a rook or not.

The constraints then express that every non-occupied row must have exactly one rook, similarly every non-occupied column must have exactly one rook. The given diagonals must have the number of rooks specified for them. The constraints only need to reference squares that lie on at least one given diagonal and are not on a row/col that already has a rook. The other squares can be ignored, as it is clear they wont get a rook.

There are several packages for python that solve such kinds of problems, like scipy, numpy, and others. Here I will use the [python-constraint](https://pypi.org/project/python-constraint/) package.

```py
from constraint import Problem, ExactSumConstraint
from collections import Counter

# rooks = list of coordinates of pre-placed rooks
# diagonals = list of diagonals identified by row+col
#             It can have duplicates. Each given diagonal will
#             get exactly one new rook (not counting pre-placed rooks)
# Note that the size of the chess board is implied by the above input
# Returns a list of all rooks, including the pre-placed rooks, None if no solution

def solve(rooks, diagonals):
    n = len(rooks) + len(diagonals)
    rows = set(range(n)).difference(row for row, col in rooks)
    cols = set(range(n)).difference(col for row, col in rooks)
    diagcounter = Counter(diagonals)

    # cells that might receive a rook:
    #   ...are on rows and cols that don't have a rook yet, and
    #   ...are on one of the given diagonals
    cells = {
        (row, col) 
        for col in cols
        for row in rows
        if row + col in diagcounter
    }
    rowconstraints = [
        ([
            (row, col) for col in cols
            if (row, col) in cells
        ], 1)
        for row in rows
    ]
    colconstraints = [
        ([
            (row, col) for row in rows
            if (row, col) in cells
        ], 1)
        for col in cols
    ]
    diagconstraints = [
        ([
            (row, diag - row) for row in rows
            if diag - row in cols 
        ], numRooks)
        for diag, numRooks in diagcounter.items()
    ]
    constraints = rowconstraints + colconstraints + diagconstraints
    # Translate to how python-constraint package works 
    problem = Problem()
    problem.addVariables(cells, [0, 1])
    for cells, numRooks in constraints:
        problem.addConstraint(ExactSumConstraint(numRooks), cells)
    solution = next(problem.getSolutionIter(), None)
    if solution:
        return sorted([cell for cell, hasrook in solution.items() if hasrook] + rooks)
```

Here is an example run:

```py
# Example input (see image below)
rooks = [(1, 2)]                    # row, col coordinates of each known rook
diagonals = [3, 7, 7, 7, 9, 10, 10] # diags identified by row+col sum

solution = solve(rooks, diagonals)
print(solution)
```

The input represents this chess board and constraints:

[image]

There is one pre-placed rook (indicated with R). The diagonals in  are colored, and their frequency indicated with a number. For example, the yellow one needs to get 3 rooks and is identified by the number 7 since its squares have coordinates that add up to 7.

A solution to this test case is this:

[image]

... and the output of the above example run is:

```py
[(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 5), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 4), (6, 1), (7, 0)]
```